# Chrome Web Store does not automatically launches additional app setup

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-app, google-apps-marketplace, chrome-web-store

I have created and published an application for domain use in Chrome Web Store. 
Unfortunately, after the installation of the app in Google Marketplace App the additional app setup is not launched automatically but requires admin to manually launch the "Additional app setup" URL with (Recommended) text below it.

Previously (for applications deployed to Google Marketplace Apps), the setup URL was launched automatically after installation process.

Is it possible to automatically launch the setup URL after app installation?

Thank you,
E

Answer (score 0):

Add it into your onInstalled or onLaunched event handler. window.open() it after doing a first-run check that you store in chrome.storage.sync.

Comment: Does that mean that I have to launch the application first? Is there any way to run it immediately after install before the app has been ever launched? Thank you.

Comment: Sounds like you haven't read my full comment or tried it with real code.

Comment: Hi! Truly said I did not really understood your answer. Could you please point me to proper documentation regarding that. I am aware only about the scripts running in background (https://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_lifecycle). Are you talking about that one? Thank you a lot, E